# Java scanners - skip all "non-int" and "less than 0" inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to loop through and skip all inputs that are less or equal 0 or non integers.

I have written this code, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

```
while(!userInput.hasNextInt() || userInput.nextInt() <= 0) {
    userInput.next();
}
return userInput.nextInt();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, what actually does not work?

Comment: it doesnt return the first valid number you enter, you have to enter 2 valid numbers and it will return the second

Comment: Got it, thank you! Could you please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change a logic a bit, for example:

```
while (userInput.hasNext()) {
    if (userInput.hasNextInt()) {
        int intValue = userInput.nextInt();
        if (intValue > 0) {
            return intValue;
         }
    }
    userInput.next();
}
```

Because when you're trying to verify that int value is less or equal zero `userInput.nextInt() <= 0`, you're actually getting the value. 
So, if it's not true, you will go to this line `return userInput.nextInt();`, but cursor will already be on the next value.

Comment: problem with this solution is that it doesnt let the user reenter a number if it wasnt valid

Comment: @LukasPetersson I've changed the solution, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether there is any user input or not. If there is take the input and then process it else continue with the loop.

```
while(userInput.hasNextInt()){
       int a=userInput.nextInt();
       if(a>=0){
          return a; 
       }else
          continue;
 }
```

Comment: problem with this solution is that it doesnt let the user reenter a number if it wasnt valid

Comment: It will. Its continuing the loop. It will again wait for another user Input. Check again.Continue doesn't mean breaking the loop, it means the loop will iterate again.